# i have installed pydumpck but get "'pydumpck' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: python, decompiling

I have installed pydumpck with pip install pydumpck, but when I try to call pydumpck command I get "'pydumpck' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Can someone help? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJfFy.png)

Try to solve this issue

Comment: Does this help? [how to fix 'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851955/how-to-fix-auto-py-to-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). I don't use Windows myself, but this looks like a similar situation and the answers look good. The one about the `PATH` is probably the one you want.

Comment: maybe it doesn't create script to run directly `pydumpck`. Maybe it will work as `python -m pydumpck`. OR maybe it needs `/full/path/to/pydumpck`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.